# Rails route any path to static file in the public

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, single-page-application

I'm in the process of the building static page application.

Every path query, `/` (root), `/sessions/new`, `/posts/` should return file placed in the `public/index.html` without redirecting (I need to save path because of inner javascripts module works with it).

How can I do that?

Comment: link to controller and deliver file from controller

Comment: I think it's ugly - to write controller for this case

Comment: no chance without redirect

Comment: Let's wait another answers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Huan Son was right, no chances without controller.

The best way I've found - is to write a controller for sending static file placed in the `public` folder.

Answer (score 1):

Adding an `after_action` might work, this will be inherited to all controllers, thus allowing every controller method to render this file. I don't think you could directly serve static files in routes.rb (If anyone knows otherwise, please do correct me)

```
# app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # ...
  # ...

  after_action render_index

  def render_index
    render file: 'index.html'
  end

  # ...
  # ...
end
```